# time to get in array of bitarrays

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I have a problem that I don't understand, in that code:

```
ilProbekUcz= valuesUcz.Count; //valuesUcz is the list of <float[]>
for (int i = 0; i < ilWezlowDanych; i++) nodesValueArrayUcz[i] = new BitArray(ilProbekUcz);
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < ilProbekUcz; i++)
{
        int index = 0;
       linia = (float[])valuesUcz[i];//removing this line not solve problem
        for (int a = 0; a < ileRazem; a++)
                for (int b = 0; b < ileRazem; b++)
                        if (a != b)
                        {
                                bool value = linia[a] >= linia[b];
                                nodesValueArrayUcz[index][i] = value;
                                nodesValueArrayUcz[ilWezlowDanychP2 + index][i] = !value;
                                index++;
                        }
}
sw.Stop();
```

When i increase size of `valuesUcz` 2x, time of execution is 4x bigger

When i increase size of `valuesUcz` 4x, time of execution is 8x bigger 
etc ...

(`ileRazem`,`ilWezlowDanych` is the same)

I understand: increase of `ilProbekUcz` increases size of `BitArrays` but i test it many times and it is no problem - time should grow linearly - in code:

```
ilProbekUcz= valuesUcz.Count; //valuesTest is the list of float[]
for (int i = 0; i < ilWezlowDanych; i++) nodesValueArrayUcz[i] = new BitArray(ilProbekUcz);
BitArray test1 = nodesValueArrayUcz[10];
BitArray test2 = nodesValueArrayUcz[20];
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < ilProbekUcz; i++)
{
        int index = 0;
       linia = (float[])valuesUcz[i];//removing this line not solve problem
        for (int a = 0; a < ileRazem; a++)
                for (int b = 0; b < ileRazem; b++)
                        if (a != b)
                        {
                                bool value = linia[a] >= linia[b];
                                test1[i] = value;
                                test2[i] = !value;
                                index++;
                        }
}
```

time grows linearly, so the problem is to take a `BitArray` from the array...

Is any method to do it faster ? (i want time to grow linearly)

Comment: *...time grows **linearly**, so the problem is to take a BitArray from the array...

Is any metod to do it faster ? (i want time to grows **lineary**)* ... O(1 * n) = O(2 * n) = ... = O(c * n) = O(n), where c is a constant.

Comment: What is `ileRazem`?

Comment: size of linia - i measure times at 1440, 2880, 5760

Comment: but "linia" is not a problem, I turned it into a constant and times are the same

Comment: You can remove `linia` and use `bool value = valuesUcz[ i ][ a ] >= valuesUcz[ i ][ b ];`. You said it didn't help. If you don't tell as what you want to accomplish we can not help you. All we can see is 3 `for` loops doing something.

Comment: what @NiVeR said is correct. Your time is increasing linearly.

Comment: i don't understand: lenghts of BitArrays are the same - I change number of bitarrays eg 4x - so first loop is 4x longer - so why time is more than 8x longer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that measuring time there are many factors that makes them inacurate. The biggest factor when you have huuuuuge arrays as in your example is `cashe misses`. Many times the same thing written when taking account of *cashe*, can be as much as 2-5 or more times faster. Two words how cashe works, very roughly. Cache is memory inside cpu. It is waaaaaaaaaaaaaay faster than ram so when you want to fetch a variable from memory you want to make sure this variable is stored in cache and not in ram. If it is stored in cache we say we have a `hit` otherwise a `miss`. Some times, not so often, a program is so big that it stores variables in hard drive. In that case you have a huuuuuuuuuuuge hit in delay when you fetch these! An example of cache:

Lets say we have an array of 10 elements in memory(ram)

[image]

when you get the first element `testArray[0]`, because *testArray[0]* is not in cache the cpu brings this value **along** with a number(lets say 3, the number depends on the cpu) of adjacent elements of the array eg it stores to cache `testArray[0], testArray[1], testArray[2], testArray[3]`

[image]

Now when we get `testArray[1]` it is in cache so we have a `hit`. The same with `testArray[2]` and `testArray[3]`. `testArray[4]` isn't in cache so it gets `testArray[4]` along with another 3 `testArray[5], testArray[6], testArray[7]`

[image]

and so on...
Cache `misses` are very costly. That means you may expect an array of double the size is going to be accessible double the time. But this is not true. Bigger arrays more `misses`
and the time may increase 2 or 3 or 4 or more times from what you expect. This is normal. In your example that is what is happening. From 100 million elemensts(first array) you go t0 400 million (second one). The `misses`are not double but waaay more as you saw. A very cool trick has to do with the way you access an array. In your example `ba1[j][i] = (j % 2) == 0;` is way worse than `ba1[i][j] = (j % 2) == 0;`. The same with `ba2[j][i] = (j % 2) == 0;` and `ba1[i][j] = (j % 2) == 0;`. You can test it. Just reverse `i and j`. It has to do with the way the 2D array is stored in memory so in the second case you have more `hits` that the first one.

Comment: Thank You, i know that ba[i][j] is faster - it time grows lineary ;), the algorithm needs to fill them in order from first code ... i need to think abaut it -  but i have a question: do you know some metods let me affects what is in cache ?

Comment: @barpas You can't. Cpu does it automatically as long as data is sequental, one next to other. In your loops 99,9999% of the time is wasted in fetching values to cache. So if these values are not next to each other you have big issue. You have to understand `array[0][0]` and `array[1][0]` are **not** together in memory. But `array[0][0]` and `array[0][1]` are! Tell me what your algorithm does so I can help you in your code.

Comment: as You can see there is array of lines, thre are values - it compare every values in linie (float[]) and put result to proper bitarray, lines are ordered by time,  bitarray are ordered by compared values each bit in bitarray is next period of time

Comment: @barpas I need the exact code otherwise i cant help you